# Acct-Input-Octets Unknown Module

Tags: freeradius

I installed FreeRadius 3 on CentOS 7. I got this error message:

> Instantiating module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log /etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/main/oracle/queries.conf[28]: Failed parsing expanded string: /etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/main/oracle/queries.conf[28]: ...ed-IP-Address}','%{Service-Type}','%{Acct-Input-Octets:-0}','%{Acct-Output-Octets:-0}','%{NA... /etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/main/oracle/queries.conf[28]:               ^ Unknown module

The Acct-Input-Octets considered as Unknown Module.
I enabled "redis" and "rediswho" and installed redis-server. even I think that "redis" is not the module that I missed.

Why FreeRadius can not deal with "Acct-Input-Octets"?
What is the required module in mods-enabled that I should activate to use "Acct-Input-Octets"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Just changed

```
%{Acct-Input-Octets:-0}
```

to

```
%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}
```